# Chef: Force use of modified attributes in template

Tags: templates, attributes, chef-infra

I have noob chef question. I need to update a directory path in a template and copy it to two different places. The directory path is different for each instance although the template file is the same.

I have the following attributes file (default.rb):

```
node['conf_dir'] = '/opt/app/etc'
```

I have the following template file (myconfig.conf.erb):

```
ConfigDir = <%= node['conf_dir'] %>
```

I have the following in my recipe file:

```
template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end

# update conf dir for new app
node['conf_dir'] = '/opt/newapp/etc'
template '/opt/newapp/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end
```

I'd like to see the ConfigDir in /opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf to have a value of '/opt/app/etc' and I'd like to see the ConfigDir in /opt/newapp/etc/myconfig.conf to have a value of '/opt/newapp/etc'. When I try to run the recipe, configDir for both app points to the newapp directory. Why is my update to the attribute not taking affect? Is something like this possible with chef? If so, any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not advised.  If you need two different values for two different files, then you really should use two different node attributes.

attributes/default.rb

```
default['app']['conf_dir'] = '/opt/app/etc'
default['new_app']['conf_dir'] = '/opt/new_app/etc'
```

template

```
ConfigDir = <%= @conf_dir %>
```

recipe

```
template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do 
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  mode '0644'
  variables({   
     :conf_dir => node['app']['conf_dir']
  })
end

template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  mode '0644'
  variables({   
     :conf_dir => node['new_app']['conf_dir']
  })
end
```

Comment: The end of my answer wasn't enough ? :) (yours is more concise and right to the point)

Comment: Tensibai, Either you added the second part after I read your answer, or I read it too quickly and missed the "better approach" part.  I certainly didn't mean to step on your toes.  Sorry

Comment: No problem, if you missed the second part, other may have too (and my answer is a little TL;DR;). So I added a warning at top about it :) (But I'm sure I wrote it at once :p )

Answer (score 2):

This answer has two part, one fixing the original question, the second giving a better approach for this use case.

1)

As I highly discourage the way mentioned in the other answer I'll write one taking advantage of [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation):

Template:

```
ConfigDir = <%= @conf_dir %>
```

Recipe:

```
template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
  variables( conf_dir: node['conf_dir'] )
end

# update conf dir for new app
ruby_block "update conf dir" do
  block
    node['conf_dir'] = '/opt/newapp/etc'
  end
end

template '/opt/newapp/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
    variables(lazy { conf_dir: node['conf_dir'] } )
end
```

This way the variable for the template is really configured by the recipe, whatever the environment, role or other recipes does as the change in the node object is done just before the template rendering, the lazy evaluation differ the resolution of what value is `node['config']` until it is needed (at convergence phase)

---

2)

Side note: The way you're doing things is highly error prone and will become a nightmare to maintain, I suggest you review your way of doing things in something like:

Attribute file:

```
node['apps']['app']['conf_dir'] = '/opt/app/etc'
node['apps']['app']['owner'] = 'root'
node['apps']['app']['group'] = 'root'
node['apps']['newapp']['conf_dir'] = '/opt/newapp/etc'
node['apps']['newapp']['owner'] = 'root'
node['apps']['newapp']['group'] = 'root'
```

Alternative syntax for attributes defining a hash instead:

```
node['apps']['app'] = { conf_dir: '/opt/app/etc',
                        owner: 'root',
                        group: 'root' 
                      }
```

Template:

```
ConfigDir = <%= @conf_dir %>
```

Recipe:

```
node['apps'].each do |app,properties|
  template "/opt/#{app}/etc/myconfig.conf" do
    source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
    owner properties['owner']
    group properties['group']
    mode '0644'
    variables( conf_dir: properties['conf_dir'] )
  end
end
```

This way you're not messing anymore with node object at runtime/compile time and you have an easy path to add another app without copy pasting the template definition again.

For those wondering the mix between double quotes and single quote, the interpolation of variables `#{var}` takes place only inside double quotes, and it's usage to keep single quotes on fixed string to differentiate them.

Answer (score -1):

**[NOT ROBUST SOLUTION]**
Attribute defined at the same precedence level **in the recipe** has higher priority over the one which is defined **in attributes file** (automatic one by Ohai is never changed). You can check [attributes precedence in details](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence). In your case, I would go with template and variable approach, so your recipe will look smth like:

```
require 'pp'
node.override['conf_dir'] = '/tmp' 
pp node.debug_value('conf_dir')

template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  mode '0644'
  variables({   
     :conf_dir => node.default['conf_dir']
  })
end

template '/opt/app/etc/myconfig.conf' do
  source 'myconfig.conf.erb'
  mode '0644'
  variables({   
     :conf_dir => node.override['conf_dir']
  })
end
```

Also your attribute file you need to explicitly specify precedence level, so it will be `node.default['conf_dir'] = '/opt/app/etc'` and template file will be using variable `ConfigDir = <%= @conf_dir %>`. In the code snippet above I also left `pp node.debug_value('conf_dir')` line which is *extremely* useful for debugging.

You can override attributes at run time if you're using `include_recipe`, but I cannot find it useful in your case.

Comment: @DnjAbc Welcome to SO. If Dmitry's answer solved the problem, please click the check icon next to it and "select as the answer".

Comment: "Attribute defined in the recipe has higher priority over the one which is defined in attributes file. " **This is absolutely false !** In the recipe you can do the same as in attribute files (node.default, node.normal, node.override, node.set etc.) and it will be evaluated after attributes files. The `node` object is just superfluous in attribute files as the code is done to populate the node attribute tree from them.

Comment: This answer is at all an awfull hack, accessing atributes at a level of precedence should be avoided, when a role will come with an override ont his value, you'll bang your head on wall finding why it's not the value in the recipe.

Comment: @Tensibai I appreciate your feedback, but at the link to the documentation it provided is clearly pointed out what is **good** and what's is **bad** in terms of using attributes.

Comment: @Tensibai regarding your comment about precedence - The author of the questions can again check the link I have included and he will find out all the priorities. I was answering his question for his case.

Comment: @Dmitry You're messing between setting an attribute at a specific level, and getting it. The doc never say that you should access an attribute at a specific precedence level. You're just breaking the description paradigm a configuration management system is about. And you should not be relying on an external link for a SO answer.

Comment: It will be also great to hear from you - ideal solution for his use case @Tensibai or discuss it in chat.

Comment: "I was answering his question for his case." And I maintain you're spreading a bad method by accessing attributes at a specific level of precedence.

Comment: @Dmitry see my answer just above, the end of it is how to handle those cases ideally

Comment: I got your point @Tensibai, makes sense. Shall I remove this answer?

Comment: At least add a warning this has a limited use, after having useed all level of precedence you can't add any new entry, and if a wrapper cookbook is used, it can't enforce it's value with force_override, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88489/discussion-between-tensibai-and-dmitry).