# Chef: Using role json with a template instead of default.rb

Tags: json, chef-infra

I'm configuring Splunk forwarder /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf file based on the role that a particular host has.  I've defined monitor, index, and sourcetype role specific values which are (obviously) stored as JSON.

Most examples show how to create a file using a template resource in a recipe where the arguments passed to the template resource are stored as entries in the attributes/default.rb file.

Now I found an previous question which is close to what I'm attempting to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332178/3481957), but it assumes that the attributes are a hash rather than JSON.

My hesitation in using this approach is not only that the format is a hash and not JSON, but also the fact that there are multiple entries for monitor, index, and sourcetype for each application running on that host that we need to send to the Splunk indexers.  So the template.erg will need to iterate through the JSON and append the new entries for each application log.  A small example of the role JSON is below.

```
{
  "chef_type": "role",
  "default_attributes": {
     "gateway_common_input": {
       "monitor":   "/home/app/logs/common",
       "index":   "gateway_common",
       "sourcetype":   "common" },
     "gateway_recv_counter_input": {  
       "monitor":  "/home/app/logs/recv_counter",
       "index":   "gateway_recv_counter",
       "sourcetype":   "recv_counter" },
     "gateway_send_counter_input": { 
       "monitor":   "/home/app/logs/send_counter",
       "index":   "gateway_send_counter",
       "sourcetype":   "send_counter" }

  },
  "description": "Role for Gateway hosts",
  "env_run_lists": {},
  "json_class": "Chef::Role", 
  "name": "rgateway",
  "override_attributes": {},
  "run_list": [
    "role[gateway]",
    "recipe[gateway_dimensions]"
  ]
}
```

Edit:
To help clarify matters in the above JSON which defines the "rgateway" role there are three application logs that need to be added to the Splunk Forwarder inputs.conf file; gateway_common_input, gateway_recv_counter_input, and gateway_send_counter_input each with their own settings for "monitor", "index", and "sourcetype".

The inputs.conf file would then have three entries like this:

```
[monitor:///home/app/logs/common/]
disabled = false
index = gateway_common
sourcetype = common

[monitor:///home/app/logs/recv_counter/]
disabled = false
index = gateway_recv_counter
sourcetype = recv_counter

[monitor:///home/app/logs/send_counter]
disabled = false
index = gateway_send_counter
sourcetype = send_counter
```

Other roles may have five entries or only one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when outputting JSON from Chef, you'll build the data structure in Ruby code and then just call `.to_json` on it to get a string.

Comment: I'm not outputting JSON but rather reading the role attributes when constructing a file using a template resource.  I haven't found any clear examples of creating a file using a template resource with role attributes which are stored as JSON on the Chef server.  That, unfortunately is my problem.

Comment: You don't use "role attributes" directly, they get merged in to the node attributes at the start of the Chef run and you access them through the normal `node` object like all other node attributes.

Comment: Ok, that still leaves two problems:
1. That means the node has to converge first before I can read the role attributes.
2. The recipe would have to know all the attributes for every role or have a way to discover the attributes at run time (the problem about iterating over the JSON I mention in the OP).

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you may have some fundamental misunderstandings of how node attributes work.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for [here](https://github.com/biola/chef-cookbooks).  You were correct coderanger in that I wasn't quite grasping how role attributes function.  So I didn't quite understand how to parse the nested attributes in my role JSON.  The answer lies with configuring my template ERB correctly.  In the cookbook I link to the node role attributes are passed in as a hash and then the ERB iterates over the hash.  Here's the template ERB from that cookbook to illustrate

```
<% @splunk_monitors.each_with_index do |parameters, index| -%>
# Begin new monitor stanza
#
<% parameters.each_key do |monitor_name| -%>
[monitor://<%= parameters[monitor_name]['location'] %>]
disabled = false
<%= "sourcetype = " + parameters[monitor_name]['sourcetype'] if parameters[monitor_name]['sourcetype'] %>
<%= "index = " + parameters[monitor_name]['index'] if parameters[monitor_name]['index'] %>
<%= "whitelist = " + parameters[monitor_name]['whitelist'] if parameters[monitor_name]['whitelist'] %>
<%= "blacklist = " + parameters[monitor_name]['blacklist'] if parameters[monitor_name]['blacklist'] %>
<%= "host = " + parameters[monitor_name]['host'] if parameters[monitor_name]['host'] %>
<%= "crcSalt = <SOURCE>" if parameters[monitor_name]['crcSalt'] %>

<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

This is called by the default recipe in the following  manner:

```
  template "#{node['splunk']['forwarder']['home']}/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf" do
    source "inputs.conf.erb"
    if node["os"] == "linux"
      owner "root"
      group "root"
      mode "0600"
    end
    variables ({
      :splunk_monitors => node['splunk']['monitors'],
      :splunk_scripts => node['splunk']['scripts'] 
    })
    notifies :restart, resources(:service => servicename)
end
```

As you can see the recipe calls the template resource in the usual manner.  The "monitors" array is then set with a knife command (in my case it's already defined by the role).

```
"override_attributes": { "splunk": { "monitors": [ { "thisistheshortlogname": { "location": "/var/log/fileordirectory", "index": "couldomitthis", "sourcetype": "", #optional "whitelist": "", #optional "blacklist": "", #optional "crcSalt": "" #optional } } ], ...
```